# How to execute a remote alias on a linux box?

Tags: linux

Host B has an alias defined

```
alias command='ps -aef|egrep "a|b"|egrep -v "c|grep|ksh|sshd|ssh|ps |tail|bash|su \-"'
```

How can I call this alias from box A?

`ssh user@B "command"` does not work.

Comment: Ewwww. This is **really** something that should be a function, not an alias.

Comment: BTW, `command` is a shell builtin, so you don't want to override it by defining something else with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In bash

Define it as a function:

```
mycommand() {
  ps -aef | \
    egrep "a|b" | \
    egrep -v "c|grep|ksh|sshd|ssh|ps |tail|bash|su -"
}
```

...and then tell your shell to emit the source to that function when generating your remote command:

```
ssh user@B "$(declare -f mycommand); mycommand"
```

---

You *can* do something similar with an alias, but eww:

```
# define alias locally
alias mycommand='ps -aef|egrep "a|b"|egrep -v "c|grep|ksh|sshd|ssh|ps |tail|bash|su \-"'

ssh user@B bash -s <<EOF
shopt -s expand_aliases  # enable aliases on remote shell
$(alias -p)              # dump all aliases to remote shell
mycommand                # invoke desired alias
EOF
```

Note the `expand_aliases` shell option: aliases are by default available *only in interactive shells*, and a shell invoked with a command line passed as an argument is not interactive.

---

#### In ksh

Use `typeset -f` rather than `declare -f` to list functions:

```
ssh user@B "$(typeset -f); mycommand"
```

Comment: (Do you specify `ksh` anywhere in the question?)

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. I'll use bash

Comment: I don't mean to push anyone away from ksh (at least, not genuine David Korn ksh93) -- it's a good shell. Performs a lot better than bash, and bash has only recently gotten competitive on features (and still isn't all the way there yet -- finally have namevars, but still no floating-point math). On the other hand, it's worth tagging for it and mentioning it when asking questions.